# Running Many processes in Blue Prism automatically without drag and drop

Tags: rpa, blueprism

How to run many processes Starting from first and continuing to the end automatically in Blue Prism?

Method tried so far by me:

1. Created a process by using the `Process` option given in the Blue Prism, though it works but when there is an exception it terminates.

So how to design Scheduler runs all individual process continuously, one after another. Even the outcome of a process is Terminated it should run the next one.

Comment: Just use exception, recover and resume inside a loop.

Comment: "*Even the outcome of a process is Terminated it should run the next one.*" ... why not just design your processes in accordance with best practices and instead handle your exceptions and end your process gracefully?

Comment: "*So how to design Scheduler runs all individual process continuously...*" - this is pretty basic scheduler logic, have you reviewed the [help article on scheduling](https://bpdocs.blueprism.com/bp-6-10/en-us/helpSchedulesUI.htm?Highlight=schedule)?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the item under schedule management 'on exception'?

[image]

Here you can specify that when a task in a scheduler fails it can go to this task next. This way you can build your scheduler to have infinite tasks lined up and when one is finished it will perform the next one.

This however is not perfect nor recommended, typically you want a process for a business purpose and not all business purposes need to be run so you would set up a schedule for each process you want to run in a group of tasks as opposed to one schedule with all of the tasks in it. But it's doable, and that's how you'd do it. Also watch out for cleaning up after each process runs ie avoid leaving open programs running when they exception out.